# He grabbed a handful of hair and jerked at it. (what's the meaning?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He grabbed a handful of hair and jerked at it.

I understand the part 'He grabbed a handful of hair and' but can't the part 'jerked at it'.

What and when does the sentence mean and be used ? What is 'it' here?

Comment: Unsourced quote.  vtc

Answer (score 2):

The confusion does not come from *jerk* or *it*.  The confusion arises because of the word **at**.

*[verbed] at* is a type of colloquialism that often appears in English.  You will find its usage varies by region.  Additionally, this usage of *at* only applies to certain verbs.  Phrases like *poked at, tugged at, and kicked at*, all imply a half-hearted or unsuccessful attempt to do the action.  On the other hand phrases like *looked at, ran at, and threw at*, imply that the action was *directed toward* but they do not carry the implication of a half-hearted attempt.

*Kicking at* a coyote and *kicking* a coyote are two different things.

Comment: You think 'jerk at' has also the implication of 'a half-hearted, unsuccessful'?

Comment: @BEBYGONES - Good question.   If a coyote attacks my cat and I *kick at* the coyote and I successfully scare it away from my cat, can my kicks be described as unsuccessful or half-hearted?   Probably not, considering the kicks may have saved my cat's life.  Keep in mind, however, that I said *kicked-at* implies a half-hearted attempt to **do the action** (i.e. kick the coyote).    My intention was to save the cat.  I did that by *kicking-at* the coyote.  My intention was never to kick the coyote.

Answer (score 0):

[**jerk**: a sudden sharp movement.](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/jerk)
**it** refers to the hair that he grabbed.

You could rephrase it as "He grabbed a handful of hair and *suddenly pulled the handful of hair*."

Comment: It's weird that the preposition 'at' is used.

Comment: Not at all 'weird'. Part of Oxford's Definition 5 is _Expressing an incomplete or attempted action, typically involving repeated movements. - "she clutched at the thin gown"_.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - I forgot to mention that it's a definition of **at**. I think the operative word here is _repeated_. I envisage the hair-grabber tugging the hair more than once. At all events, _pulling at, gnawing at, scraping at_ etc. are perfectly normal combinations.